# Trigger Multiple Dataflow job through Cloud function in Synchronized manner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have to trigger multiple templates one by one using `Google Cloud` function in `Google Dataflow Process`. After execution of one template, the another template must be called.

```
 const google = require('googleapis');
exports.goWithTheDataFlow = function(event, callback) {
 const file = event.data;
 if (file.resourceState === 'exists' && file.name) {
   google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function (err, authClient, projectId) {
     if (err) {
       throw err;
     }
     if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
       authClient = authClient.createScoped([
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
       ]);
     }

     const dataflow = google.dataflow({ version: 'v1b3', auth: authClient });
     dataflow.projects.templates.create({
       projectId: 'testing1-180111',
       resource: {
         parameters: {
         },
         jobName: 'cloud-fn-dataflow-test',
         gcsPath: 'gs://kishan-configuration/templates/FinalConfigTable'
       }
     }, function(err, response) {
       if (err) {
         console.error("problem running dataflow template, error was: ", err);
       }
       console.log("Dataflow template response: ", response);
       callback();
     });

   });
 }
};
```

`package.json` file code is this

```
{
  "name": "kishan_kumar464",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "google-cloud": "^0.56.0",
    "googleapis": "^22.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Kishan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for workflow management system.
Do look into luigi, Airflow, etc for the purpose

Comment: No, I have Not Can U Please Share LINK, and I am Also Trying Using Pub/Sub I would put a message on a queue to trigger the next pipeline – using cloud pubsub.

Comment: Pub/Sub also Failed As We Execute PubSub to Start a new Function Its Call That Function Before Ending My Pipeline.Doesn't Matter When We Call it. i have To Run My Job using template So Graph Must be Defined in Such a Way Only.

Comment: You should explore on workflow management systems!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to create a job from a template and wait until finish. After that, you can create the next job from the template. Correct?

I think you can probably poll the job status after the job is created (job id is in the response of dataflow.projects.templates.create.

To check the status of a job, please use projects.jobs.get API.

Comment: I would put a message on a queue to trigger the next pipeline – cloud pubsub would be great for this, and it can trigger cloud functions. But I will Try Your Way Can U provide Me Some Examples

Comment: I agree with you that a "job X finished" notification via pubsub would be better. However dataflow doesn't support that for now.

Comment: I do not have an immediate example, but since you can already call dataflow API, what you can do is: (1) use dataflow.projects.jobs.get API to get a Job object. (2) check job.currentState field. If the state is JOB_STATE_DONE, go on to the next job. (3) if the job is still running or failed, handle accordingly.

Comment: Thanks But My Pipelines are Not Fixed Means 10 Jobs can Come the First after Some time More Jobs Comes So Whenever Function Triggers Then Job Starts(Means New Instance Starts).So First Job Sequencing Starts for 10 Jobs after That For next Jobs Sequence But I Need to Add That Jobs sequence in the Queue or else Thier is any Way to Trigger Template From Dataflow Program.